# Using where condition getting blank page in codeigniter mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hi i have used where condition in mysql after using that if i run the website getting the blank page.

Actually i am three department like QA Department,Development,Management.

IN Mysql i have used where condition to get only QA department list but getting blank page.

Here is my code:

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $data['records2'] = $this->index_model->get_ourteammembers();
    $data['mainpage'] = "our-team";
    $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
}
```

Model

```
function get_ourteammembers()
{

    $this->db->select('T.*');
    $this->db->from('ourteam AS T');
    $this->db->where('T.department'='QA Department');
    $q = $this->db->get();
    if($q->num_rows()>0)
    {
        return $q->result();
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `'T.department'='QA Department'` are two strings with an assignment in between.

Comment: Please accept also so any other can check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This

```
function get_ourteammembers()
{

    $this->db->select('T.*');
    $this->db->from('ourteam AS T');
    $this->db->where('T.department','QA Department');
    $q = $this->db->get();
    if($q->num_rows()>0)
    {
        return $q->result();
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Solved thank you will accept the answer after 10 mins upvoted

Comment: @user6728960 sure

Answer (score 0):

As Per [CodeIgniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html) Document you have to use ',' instead of '='

```
$this->db->where('T.department'='QA Department');
```

To

```
$this->db->where('T.department','QA Department');
```